# npm pack and missing package-lock.json

Tags: node.js, npm

from [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm/developers.html#keeping-files-out-of-your-package):

> By default, the following paths and files are ignored, so there’s no
>   need to add them to .npmignore explicitly:
>
> ```
> .*.swp
> ._*
> .DS_Store
> .git
> .hg
> .npmrc
> .lock-wscript
> .svn
> .wafpickle-*
> config.gypi
> CVS
> npm-debug.log
> ```
>
> Additionally, everything in node_modules is ignored, except for bundled dependencies. npm automatically handles this for you, so don’t bother adding node_modules to .npmignore.

when `npm pack` is executed, [`package-lock.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/package-lock-json.html) is not included in the archive.

is it a bug or is it expected and undocumented behavior?

Comment: When you install a package there's no option to "npm ci <package>"; you always use its package file, not lock file, to determine the other dependencies it needs. Otherwise you'd end up with (even more) unnecessary copies of cross-compatible shared deps. So I wouldn't expect pack to include the lock file. It even says *"it cannot be published"* in the link you just added.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: couldn't find _"it cannot be published"_ within the link and although i understand the issues that can arrise when publishing a package which includes its lock file but what about a package which is used as a standalone? kinda silly there is no way to override this behavior.

Comment: First para under the list of "various purposes" starts *"One key detail about `package-lock.json` is that it cannot be published..."* What do you mean *"package which is used as a standalone"*? If you mean some kind of tool that's not intended to be depended on, note that page on the lock file also covers an option for that. It's unclear what you think is "silly", or what the actual problem you're trying to solve is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from [`package-lock.json` docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-lock-json):

> One key detail about `package-lock.json` is that it cannot be published, and it will be ignored if found in any place other than the toplevel package.